# Force app appearance in Xcode UI tests to be light or dark

Tags: cocoa, xctest

In my UI test I'm trying to force the app's appearance (light or dark). When the system appearance is light, I can force the app to be dark with this code:

```
var app = XCUIApplication()
app.launchArguments += ["-AppleInterfaceStyle", "Dark"]
app.launch()
```

But replacing `Dark` with `Light` doesn't have any effect: if the system appearance is dark: the app remains dark. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I managed to get working suggested on [apple's developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/687260).

I don't think that the flag was applied anywhere just being set, so here we are implementing a `setupApp` method which chicks if we're debugging or not (ie, when preforming snapshots / UITests), and applies it to the view hierarchy (in this case my `Sidebar` view, my apps entry point).

Leaving the ColorScheme `nil` should default to the system default.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var colorScheme: ColorScheme? = nil

  func setupApp() {
    #if DEBUG
    if let index = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.firstIndex(where: { $0 == "-AppleInterfaceStyle" }) {
      let interfaceStyle = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments[index+1]
      if interfaceStyle == "Light" {
        self.colorScheme = ColorScheme.light
      }else{
        self.colorScheme = ColorScheme.dark
      }
    }
    #endif
  }


  var body: some View {
    Sidebar()
      .onAppear(perform: setupApp)
      .preferredColorScheme(colorScheme)
  }
}
```

source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/687260